# What is the meaning of "|" in this PHP code?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Below is the PHP code:

```
<?php 
    $a = $b['key'] | 0;
?>
```

Is it an operator?

Comment: What does the PHP documentation say?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: This is a Bitwise [Inclusive or (OR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusive_or) operator. It is a pretty much standard amongst programming languages. See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). Whenever you see an operator you don't know, check the manual on operators first. :)

Comment: @netcoder No, xor would be `^`. This is a bitwise or ;)

Comment: @netcode -- it is a bitwise **inclusive** OR

Answer (score 6):

The `|` is the [bitwise](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) OR operator.

Doing a bitwise OR with zero (`| 0`) doesn't make any sense though, as it will not flip any bits. Maybe the guy who wrote this was just a **really bad programmer** and tried to cast a string to an integer that way. He should have used a `(string)` cast instead!

Comment: if `$b['key']` value exists but is empty (null), this construct allow to assign 0 instead of null to $a (might be usefull for databases).

Comment: @NikiC, tks. What exactly do you mean by " it will not flip any bits"?
Say, if $b['key'] is integer '345', 
what is assigned to $a in this code?  is it integer '3450'? 
this operator looks strange to me..

Comment: @Tom: It will be assigned 345. Nothing changes. That's why doing `| 0` is kinda pointless ;)

Answer (score 1):

Its bitwise OR, as defined [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

For example:

```
 Bitwise Inclusive OR
( 5 = 0101) = ( 0 = 0000) | ( 5 = 0101)
( 5 = 0101) = ( 1 = 0001) | ( 5 = 0101)
( 7 = 0111) = ( 2 = 0010) | ( 5 = 0101)
( 5 = 0101) = ( 4 = 0100) | ( 5 = 0101)
(13 = 1101) = ( 8 = 1000) | ( 5 = 0101)
```

Comment: The OP asked about `|` **not `||`

Comment: @TJHeuvel Tks. This is a good example. Now I get the operator. Don't know why it's used in place of  `||` though.. since the array should contain an integer.

Answer (score 0):

`|` is a [bitwise `OR`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) function.

`||` is a [regular `OR`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Answer (score 0):

It is the bitwise OR operator.

See here for more details:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 0):

[It is performing a bitwise OR operation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

It is possible the original author of the code meant to put another `|` in to make it a logical OR (`||`), because a bitwise OR with 0 will have no effect whatsoever on the output. Although even this makes no sense, he could have simply [cast to an integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

`|` is a bitwise operator (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

`|` means "Bits that are set in either `$b['key']` or `0` are set."

Because the second part is a zero though, it will return `false` only if `$b['key']` is zero too.